# Home/Restart button in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, reset, restart

I have made a random workout generator and i would like there to be a home button on the final screen so that users can go back to the first screen and generate a new workout (my attempts so far have ended up with a second workout overlapping the first or a completely blank screen after using root.clear_widgets).Some widgets are added in the .py file and some from .kv and i never initialised my screen classes, new to kivy/python so not sure if this will affect potential solutions... Would appreciate any help! I've included my app class which has a currently empty home method called from a button in my .kv file.

```
kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class MyMainApp(App):
    sm = WindowManager()

    def home(self):
        pass


    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the ScreenManager
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html

Comment: I can change the screen the problem is if i go back to the home screen the previously generated workout/widgets aren't cleared

Comment: Can you send your whole Code and KV file?

Comment: Hey maybe this helps:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/widgets.html

Comment: thanks will see if i can get something working from there